# Prompting before building a Release configuration?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I have some specific post-build actions tied to the Release configuration, which deploys to a test environment. Is there a way to enable a pop-up warning before someone builds locally using the Release configuration for a specific project? If not, I can make my post-build actions smarter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use a custom MSBuild task. Here's an inline task to get you started.

```
<Project xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003' ToolsVersion="12.0">
  <UsingTask TaskName="ShowConfirmationPopup" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0.dll">
    <ParameterGroup>
      <Message ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <Title ParameterType="System.String" Required="false" />
      <Result ParameterType="System.Boolean" Output="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms"/>
      <Using Namespace="System.Windows.Forms" />
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs"><![CDATA[
        Result = MessageBox.Show(Message, Title ?? "MSBuild Confirmation", 
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, 
            MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) == DialogResult.Yes;
]]></Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>

  <Target Name="PromptReleaseBuild" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <ShowConfirmationPopup Message="Do Release Build?">
        <Output TaskParameter="Result" PropertyName="DoReleaseBuild" />
    </ShowConfirmationPopup>
    <Error Text="Prompt refused" Condition="'$(DoReleaseBuild)' != 'true'" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```